# How can I make the character moving when I press a key?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I know it has been asked before but I couldn't get it to work, I'm using idle 3.6 and PyGame.

Here is the code.(I just started I have been watching some tutorials but apart from that I'm new to PyGame)

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameExit = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                location += 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a boolean flag to keep track of which key was pressed *and* released. Something like:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        gameExit = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            pressedRight = True
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            pressedRight = False

# Now in your game loop
if pressedRight:
    location += 1
```

Basically, this code emulates a way to check if the key is pressed at the current time or not, allowing you to use continuous movement.

Comment: i upvoted... it isnt visible because i dont have enough rep

Comment: oahhhhhhhh okkk